# Ember js - how to create a shared uitility

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am writing code to detect breakpoints via js using match media. In plain js, I know how to create a separate utility for this and consume it, but in Ember, how do I go about it, would I need to create a helper or something else.

**Plain JS code**:

```
define('viewportDimension', function() {
    var viewportSize ={
        mqMaxTablet : '959px',
        isTablet: function(){
            if(matchMedia){
                var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width:" + this.mqMaxTablet+ ")");
                mq.addListener(this.viewportChanged);
                this.viewportChanged(mq);
            }
        },
        viewportChanged: function(mq){
            if(mq.matches){
                return true;
            }
        }
    };
    return viewportSize;
});
```

**Ember Controller:**

```
isTablet: function (){
 viewportDimension.isTablet();
}.property('')
```

I understand the above code will not work. I dont know how to make it more Ember'ish type. The "isTablet" property should be set to true, as soon as the media query match is done.

Started converting my plain js to emberish (as below), but dont know how to proceed.

```
define('viewportDimension',function(){
    var viewportSize = Ember.Object.extend({
        isTablet: function(){
            alert("1");

        }.property('')
    });
    return viewportSize;


});

Ember.Application.initializer({
    name: 'viewport-dimension',
    initialize: function(container,app){
        require('viewportDimension',function(object){
            app.ViewportDimension = object
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Maybe this module is suitable for you https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-responsive

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani - Thanks for the link, I think it could help, but sadly, there is a long process to include any add on, in my project. Hence, I am looking for some quick implementation, which i could do

Comment: I don't understand why there is a long process to include any addon. Anyway which version of ember do you use?

Comment: Its 1.11 version, I know its old, plans are on to upgrade after some time.

Comment: I'm providing a twiddle for this

Comment: Sure, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at [simple-breakpoint-detector](https://ember-twiddle.com/51db3f95e0c2d99529c32f25d41deeb4)

Comment: Thanks, will try this. One thing to ask, you have created this as a service, so in Ember way, is that correct to create a service for a utility which is used across app.

Comment: Services are singleton. And using for this, is not a problem.

Comment: @whyAto8 this is just for getting idea. you can move it to utils too.

Comment: yeah, so if i use it in uitls, what would i use "Ember.Object.extend" ?

Comment: Yes. You need to use `Ember.Object.extend`. Or event in helper you can move it

Comment: @whyAto8 i added helper too in twiddle : https://ember-twiddle.com/51db3f95e0c2d99529c32f25d41deeb4

Comment: Hey, I just realised, that you have used window.resize event, whereas this should not be used, as the code is already adding a listener for that and will do its job. Do you think, removing window.resize would impact it?

Comment: @whyAto8 it's not important. I just show how integrate in ember. You can change it what ever you want

Comment: Okay, I  tried it. But the twiddle is not working for me. I am geting error inside the if(mq.matches) as soon as I resize window and hit breakpoint. The error is "this.set if not a function".

Comment: I have just removed the window.resize code. Here is the twiddle for my file -responsive - https://ember-twiddle.com/21aa1d24ebd6ad29c9c1503f278e6ade?openFiles=responsive.js%2C . If you take this code in earlier twiddle, you might see the issue. The first time page loads "this" object points to ember object in "viewportChanged" but when we resize and hit breakpoint, "this" object points to "mq" , hence the error "this.set" is not a function

Comment: You should bind that method. In this line `mq.addListener(this.viewportChanged);` Add bound function to listeners

Comment: Didnt get that, could you please elaborate

Comment: I mean this : `mq.addListener(Ember.run.bind(this, this.viewportChanged));`

Comment: Awesome, it all worked now. Such a relief. Thank you so much for all the help. :-)